# WPF ListBox getting item datacontext OnMouseOver

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, listbox, datacontext

I currently have a view that contains a ListBox bound to a a collection of view models and a user control that I would like to bind to the current item that the mouse is over.  How can I get the current highlighted item in the list and bind it to the user control using only XAML and code in the View Model?

**Edit**: The following image might be more descriptive of the intended action.
[alt text http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/6263/34548010.png](http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/6263/34548010.png)

Comment: MVVM is not a religion. If you can solve the problem with a little of code behind, go for it.

Comment: I'm sensing a little peer pressure here to go 'against the pattern' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As eduardo said, sometimes to make a solution in pure MVVM is too complicated.

if you reformulate your question and provide some code, you can get more answers.

Comment: I have found that especially when it comes to animation some code behind might be necessary.  It also doesn't break the pattern since the animation is a part of the view and therefore enforces separation of UI and Logic.